# What does this argument to the \symbol command mean

Tags: symbols, xetex, enumitem

I was looking at this page [here](http://www.cv-templates.info/2009/08/modern-latex-cv-template-advanced-graphics/) and came across this line which I don't understand.

```
\symbol{"E052}
```

Can you explain to me what the significance of `E052` is, and how I could modify this command to give me different symbols.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means the number of the glyph in the font encoding. By default, `OT1` encoding. In XeTeX, `EU1` encoding is used, i.e. Unicode.

`"E502` is hexadecimal number 58626 in TeX. You can use \symbol{"E502} or `\symbol{58626}` or `\symbol{'162402}`(octal number) for this symbol. It is in private range of Unicode. See http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Unicode/Character_reference/E000-EFFF